# Cluster of Triangles: Which Can See the Outside?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, raycasting

I have a mesh of triangles that is like the blueprints of a structure, where some triangles represent interior things. I want to isolate just the triangles that form the sort of exterior. The mesh might not always be a sealed surface that encloses the interior things, so I am assuming that any triangles that have no line of sight to the outside or bounding box must be interior things.

If I have a bunch of triangles in 3D space, how do I figure out which ones have an unobstructed straight line of sight to the outside or bounding box, and which ones are fully shielded by other triangles? I have a bounding box and an "up" vector.

I probably have to loop over each possibly-obstructing triangle, but I'm not sure how to record the like obstruction progress for each one.

I tried breaking the bounding box into triangles and rephrasing it as a question of "Can triangle A see triangle B?" but recording the progress still seems difficult. There could be a group of tiny triangles that collectively covers triangle B, but each one individually cuts off 0% of triangle A from seeing triangle B and cuts off 0% of triangle B from seeing triangle A.

I saw a trick where you can send a line out and count whether it hits the mesh an even or odd number of times, but I think that only applies to polyhedra. This mesh could be two or more polyhedra joined at the faces, or it might be an open shape, both of which would make that trick not work.

I figured out I can save resources by like, once I identify that a triangle is fully shielded from the outside, I no longer need to consider it as a possibly-obstructing triangle, since if it blocks a ray leading to the outside, another triangle that is not fully shielded must also block that ray afterward or else the fully shielded triangle would see the outside.

But I haven't figured out how to solve this problem.